# Cannot convert input (ImageButton) to jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got a gridview with ImageButton that launches edit form. I need to get surrounding element (Row) to determine the ID.
The problem is that onClientClick I launch a JS function and send 'this' as a parameter. Now I try to make jQuery object out of it like this:

```
$(sender)
```

But i receive such error:

> Error: An invalid or illegal string was specified

I don't know what is the problem :/
Here I put also HTML of my control:

```
<input id="ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_GrdTestScenarios_grdTestScenario_ctl02_EditButton" type="image" style="border-width:0px;" onclick="return openPopup(this, url , title);" alt="Delete" src="Images/edit.png" name="ctl00$PlaceHolderMain$GrdTestScenarios$grdTestScenario$ctl02$EditButton">
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: If you create a click event with jquery, you can acess the clicked element with `$(this)`.

Comment: You mean like this ? $( ."class" ).click(function() {
  some code
});

Comment: openPopup is my function that executes build in Sharepoint openPopup -> SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog(options);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your opening post, your input is like this:

```
<input id="ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_GrdTestScenarios_grdTestScenario_ctl02_EditButton" type="image" style="border-width:0px;" onclick="return openPopup(this, url , title);" alt="Delete" src="Images/edit.png" name="ctl00$PlaceHolderMain$GrdTestScenarios$grdTestScenario$ctl02$EditButton">
```

This means in the `openPopup()` function in your JS file should look like this:

```
function openPopup(this, url, title) {
    var $this = $(this); // gets your the element that was clicked
    var row = $this.parents("tr"); // gets the parent row depending on HTML structure
}
```

OR - you can include your JS in the aspx page like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#<%=EditButton.ClientID%>").click(function() { 
        var $this = $(this); // gets the element that is clicked
        var row = $this.parents("tr"); // gets parent row depending on HTML structure
    });
});

</script>
```

Comment: The problem was, like almost always - banal. I haven't imported jQuery file into the .aspx which was causing this behaviour. That's weird anyway, because when I tried to use i.e. $(".class") it worked properly. Your post gave me this clue somehow :) Many thanks for your help guys !

Comment: No problem, glad you got sorted. Happy to help in some way!

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to launch a popup on clicking that element you can use jQuery selector and grab the ID (although the id is quite long):

```
$("#ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_GrdTestScenarios_grdTestScenario_ctl02_EditButton").click(function(){
    //launch
});
```

This will catch the click event on the input and execute whatever code you use for launching your popup.

Comment: you should use: `$("#<%=EditButton.ClientID%>")` for your selector as it looks like a server side control.

Comment: Jordan I've got multiple such buttons, so that isn't the right way probably :/. Dave, using your method I need to run a loop to cover all the buttons, right ?

Comment: I was replying to Jordan's answer, sorry. But, no you wouldn't need to loop through all. You would do `$("#<%=EditButton.ClientID%>").click(function() { $(this) });` - `$(this)` would get you the button that has been clicked. To get the row element you could do `$(this).parents("tr");` depending on your HTML structure.

Comment: But this means that I have to have my function in .aspx and not in .js file. Because <%=EditButton.ClientID%> can't be passed as a param, right ? I can live with it, just asking.

Comment: @97ldave , you are welcome to edit my answer to something more suitable and take credit if you would like. Thank you for the comment.

Comment: @Jordan.J.D, no its ok, no intention of taking credit. Was just pointing out an improvement. Nothing wrong with your answer based on OP.